# How to solve private access in [subclass]

Tags: java, composition, super

i just started to do java programming, completely new here. apparenly i searched the forum and dint find my solution to this error.

Im using jdk1.7.0_60 and this is my homework.

My problem is when i tried to compile my subclass which is the **Car.java** the compiler is showing

```
error: manufacturer has private access in Vehicle
System.out.println("Manufacturer: +manufacturer); // this error also appear at (Owner :+owner)
```

But the source code in Owner.java and vehicle.java, it is given by the question so it cant be change.

this is **owner.java**

```
public class Owner{
private String name;
private String id;

public Owner(String name,String id){
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Owner Name: "+this.name):
    System.out.println("Owner ID: "+this.id);

}
}
```

this is **vehicle.java**

```
public class Vehicle{
private String manufacturer;
private Owner owner;

public Vehicle(String manufacturer,Owner owner){
    this.manufacturer =manufacturer;
    this.owner=owner;
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Manufacturer: "+this.manufacturer);
    this.owner.display();
}
}
```

this is subclass **car.java**

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
private String model;
private String RegNumber;
private boolean registered = false;

public Car(String manufacturer,Owner owner,String model){
    super(manufacturer,owner);

    this.model=model;

}

public void registerCar(String regNo){
    if (registered = false){

        RegNumber = regNo;
        registered = true;
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Registered");
    }
}

public void display(){
super.display();
    System.out.println("printed in car class");
    System.out.println("Manufacturer: " +manufacturer); //the error
    System.out.println("Owner : " +owner);// and here 
    System.out.println("Model : " +model);
    System.out.println("Registration Number: "+RegNumber);

    }
}//subclass
```

and this is my main class **obj.java**

sadly, my main class contains error too

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class obj{
public static void main(String [] args){


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Insert Owner's name : ");
String ownername=sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Insert Owner's id : ");
String ownerid=sc.nextLine();   

System.out.print("Enter car manufacturer name : ");
String mname=sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter car model : ");
String carmodel=sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter car registration number : ");
String regnumber=sc.nextLine();

Owner newowner = new Owner(ownername,ownerid);
Car newcar = new Car(mname,ownername,carmodel);

}
}
```

The error message from the compiler.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>javac obj.java
obj.java:22: error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;
Car newcar = new Car(mname,ownername,carmodel);
         ^
  required: String,Owner,String
  found: String,String,String
  reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to Owner by method invocation conversion

.\Car.java:28: error: manufacturer has private access in Vehicle
            System.out.println("Manufacturer: " +manufacturer);
                                                 ^
.\Car.java:29: error: owner has private access in Vehicle
            System.out.println("Owner : " +owner);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly whats wrong:

> Car newcar = new Car(mname,ownername,carmodel);
>
> required: String,Owner,String
>
> found: String,String,String

You are passing in a string, 'owernername', when you need to pass in an object of type Owner.

> .\Car.java:28: error: manufacturer has private access in Vehicle
>
> ```
>        System.out.println("Manufacturer: " +manufacturer);
> ```
>
> .\Car.java:29: error: owner has private access in Vehicle
>
> ```
>        System.out.println("Owner : " +owner);
> ```

These two errors are caused because Car does not have a variable called 'manufacturer' and 'owner'. Vehicle does. 'manufacturer' and 'owner' are private in Vehicle, so you do not have access to them in Car.

To allow Car to display its superclass Vehicle's 'manufacturer' and 'owner' variables, you must write a public function in Vehicle like 'getManufacturer' which returns the private variable 'manufacturer. Do the same with 'owner'.

Comment: How do i pass object of type Owner? Ive tried Car newcar=new Car(mname,owner,carmode); the compiler show obj.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
Car newcar = new Car(mname,Owner,carmodel);

Comment: First, in your main(), create an Owner. What is required to create an owner? A (string) name and a an (string) id. I knew this because I looked at the Class Owner's constructor. You could create a new object Owner by 'Owner owner = new Owner(ownername,ownerid)'. Then create a new car like so: 'Car newcar=new Car(mname,owner,carmode);' Make sure that you create 'owner' AFTER you have created 'ownername' and 'ownerid' and BEFORE you try and create 'newcar'.

Comment: 'Owner owner = new Owner(ownername,ownerid);' - dont forget the semi colon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "protected" access for manufacturer.  "private" does not allow subclasses to access the field.

Comment: Yes,Apparently i cant change the access modifier. It was given by the question.